# Given the base of a triangle and ratio of tangents of half of the base angles, Find the locus of vertex of triangle.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I'm struck with a question. While finding the locus of vertex, I'm not able to eliminate the variable involved.

In the question we are given the ratio of tangents of half base angles and the length of base of triangle. We've got to find the locus of vertex of triangle (as shown in pic )

Another method of elimination could be using Quadratic formula to simply equate the roots, but this method proves to be tedious. Are there any better ways?

Here's my working-
Here I've to find locus of vertex A and I've assumed the coordinates of variable point as (h,k)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylaXf.jpg)

Comment: you have a Problem with this equation $$m_2-\frac{1}{m_2}=\frac{h-l}{k}$$?

Comment: As u can see in pic I've got two equations I've problem in eliminating m2 to get the locus

Comment: but if you multiply by $m_2$ you will get a quadratic equation!

Comment: Yeah and then I can equate the roots of both the quadratic equations using Quadratic formula, but don't you think that will be very lengthy ? (I will have to shift terms square the sides two times to get rid of that square root), I think there is a much efficient method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $BC$ and $\frac{\tan(B/2)}{\tan(C/2)}$ are given, the projection $P$ of the incenter $I$ on $BC$ is fixed. 
Let $\Gamma$ be a circle (candidate incircle) tangent to $BC$ at $P$: the tangents from $B$ and $C$ to $\Gamma$ (different from $BC$) meet on a **hyperbola** (can you prove it?) which is the locus of the possible $A$-vertices.

[image]

Hint(s) for proving it is a hyperbola: the involved algebra implies it is a conic, and the involved simmetries imply that such a conic is unbounded and with two branches. [Blue](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/409/blue) points out a nice purely geometric alternative: $B$ and $C$ are the foci of the hyperbola above.

Comment: I can't understand your solution clearly. What do you mean by projection P of incircle I on BC?

Comment: Does it mean that if I join I (incenter) to origin to get line segment and rotate it to set it along BC then the length of the required rotated line segment is the projection ?

Comment: Here I assumed origin to be the vertex C (as done in the pic I uploaded in the solution )

Comment: Can you please make a diagram (or a picture) of your statement to make it clear to understand? It will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @ShivanshJ: improvement incoming in a few minutes.

Comment: Hyperbola-ness is immediate from the geometry. Writing $a$, $b$, $c$ for the lengths of pairs of tangent segments from $A$, $B$, $C$ to $\bigcirc I$, we have $$|\overline{AC}| - |\overline{AB}| = (a+c)-(a+b)=c-b = |\overline{CP}|-|\overline{BP}|$$ which, by the fixed nature of $P$, is a constant. So, the locus of $A$ is a hyperbola with foci $B$ and $C$, and with that constant difference of distances.

Comment: Jack, shouldn't it be specified that the ratio of tans of half the base angles is greater than 1? Otherwise, it doesn't seem like a hyperbola.